# What's going on with Plot and Mesh here?

Tags: plotting

Here's a relatively simple function, i[t,lat,i0], that plots solar intensity as a function of time, t, given latitude, lat, and a solar constant, i0:

```
 cosZenith2[dlat_, time_] := 
 Module[{rlat, hour, dec, ha, cosz, \[Sigma]},
         rlat = dlat*\[Pi]/180;
        hour = 24 FractionalPart[time];
        (* Declination *)
        dec = 0.4093*Sin[2 \[Pi] (284 + time)/365];
        (* Hour angle *)
        ha = (hour - 12) \[Pi]/12;                          
        cosz = Sin[dec] Sin[rlat] + Cos[dec] Cos[rlat] Cos[ha];
  \[Sigma] = 40;
        If[cosz >= 0, 
   cosz (1 - Exp[-\[Sigma] cosz])/(1 + Exp[-\[Sigma] cosz]), 0]
  ]

i[t_?NumberQ, lat_, i0_] := i0 cosZenith2[lat, t]
```

I first tried using a MeshFunction to insure the function is sampled when the sun is up, at t+0.5, but even when Mesh is set to 1000, or even 10000, Plot somehow still skips over most the function.

```
Plot[i[t, 42, 2000], {t, 1, 50}, Mesh -> 1000]
```

[image]

What's going on here, or have I misunderstood Mesh? PlotPoints->200 does work, but if I want to plot 1 year of data, I must set PlotPoints to at least 1000 to get around the Nyquist sampling issue. It would be more elegant to sample at Int[t]+0.5, then let Plot subdivide the function as needed to resolve the function properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

cosZenith2[dlat_, time_] := 
 Module[{rlat, hour, dec, ha, cosz, σ}, rlat = dlat*π/180;
  hour = 24 FractionalPart[time];
  (*Declination*)dec = 0.4093*Sin[2 π (284 + time)/365];
  (*Hour angle*)ha = (hour - 12) π/12;
  cosz = Sin[dec] Sin[rlat] + Cos[dec] Cos[rlat] Cos[ha];
  σ = 40;
  If[cosz >= 0, cosz (1 - Exp[-σ cosz])/(1 + Exp[-σ cosz]), 0]]
```

Use [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) rather than [`NumberQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberQ.html). Compare

```
NumberQ /@ {E, Pi, GoldenRatio}

(* {False, False, False} *)

NumericQ /@ {E, Pi, GoldenRatio}

(* {True, True, True} *)

i[t_?NumericQ, lat_, i0_] := i0 cosZenith2[lat, t]
```

Use the options [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) and [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)

```
Plot[i[t, 42, 2000], {t, 1, 50},
 PlotPoints -> 130,
 MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about NumericQ. Is there a way to specify where Plot will sample the function?

Comment: I do not know of any way to force sampling at specified locations. Increasing `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` are the documented means of plotting all features.